# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000535-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}

Tags: ado.net, adodb

Will try to ask here because didn't find any other entries for this error:

I'm getting this sporadic error when the .NET appliacation running under w3wp process. The application pool configured to run as 64 bit process. I'm using PIA ADODB mostly only recordsets as data containers.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000535-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4} failed due to the following error: 800703fa
(Checked it. Of course Recordset already installed on this machine)

On the development environment have installed 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\adodb.dll version 7.10.6070.0, WIN XP, VS 2008

On the test environment installed win 2008 server, 64 bit. The adodb.dll found under C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\adodb.dll version 7.10.2346.0

Unfortunately I can't point to any specific scenario. It happen very sporadic. But when it happen once all w3wp process is stopping to work! After iisreset the system is back and the same business process which failed right before iis reset is running sucessfully!

I'm not sure why on win 2008 server installed dll win earlier version. However the server is up-to-date with latest MS updates.

Please help!

Thanks,
Evgeny

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in the same executable. MS Office is using 32-bit code.

Comment: Config the pool to run in 32-bit mode? There is a `enable32BitAppOnWin64` metabase property.

Comment: So I must compile the webservice with x86 and then need to set this flag with IIS right? I think I did the same and received the same error!

Comment: Try running the code outside the IIS. If it fails, this is an unrelated problem. See ms kb266668